# How to store pure string in a list

Tags: python-2.7

The first item of testing_data list is `list type` in the loop , why ?

```
def test__trim_value(self):
    testing_data = ["""rtsp://172.19.1.101\n""", "3600\n\r", "\n\r900\r\n"]
    expecting_data = ["rtsp://172.19.1.101", "3600", "900"]
    for should, test_item in izip(expecting_data, testing_data):
        print(repr(test_item))
        print(type(test_item))

        got = self.txt._Txt__trim_value(test_item)
        eq_(should, got)

@classmethod
def __trim_value(cls, raw_value):
    print(type(raw_value))
    print((raw_value))
    trimmed_value = raw_value.strip()
    return trimmed_value
    pass
```

Output

```
<type 'list'>
[' rtsp', '//172.19.1.101\n']
XF'rtsp://172.19.1.101\n'
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
rtsp://172.19.1.101

'3600\n\r'
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
3600

'\n\r900\r\n'
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>

900
```

Comment: What is `expecting_data`? I'm getting a `str` type each iteration.

Comment: As posted, the type is clearly `str`. please post a complete example including the output it produces.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first part of your output (up to the `XF` characters in the third line) is from some other code that you haven't shown us. The remaining bits (starting with the quotation mark after the `XF`) are exactly what I'd expect your code to output.